# Filling triangle doesn't seem to work with PGF/TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, foreach

I was wondering if anyone had any clue on why my triangles are not filled in red within the following piece of code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d}

\usepackage[active, pdftex, tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment[{[]}]{tikzpicture}
\newcounter{number}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x  = {(-0.5cm,-0.5cm)},
                    y  = {(0.9659cm,-0.25882cm)},
                    z  = {(0cm,1cm)}]
\begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=0]
\foreach \x / \y / \label in
{1 / 0.4 / 1,
0.9 / 0.4 / 0,
1 / 0.5 / 1,
0.7 / 0.3 / 0,
0.8 / 0.4 / 0,
0.9 / 0.5 / 0,
1 / 0.6 / 1,
0.7 / 0.4 / 0,
0.4 / 0.4 / 0,
0.6 / 0.4 / 0,
0.5 / 0.4 / 0,
0.8 / 0.5 / 0,
0.9 / 0.6 / 0,
1 / 0.7 / 1,
0.7 / 0.5 / 0,
0.5 / 0.5 / 0,
0.4 / 0.5 / 0,
0.6 / 0.5 / 0,
0.8 / 0.6 / 0,
0.9 / 0.7 / 0,
1 / 0.8 / 1,
0.7 / 0.6 / 0,
0.6 / 0.6 / 0,
0.5 / 0.6 / 0}
{
\addtocounter{number}{1}
\pgfmathparse{\value{number}}\let\k\pgfmathresult
\draw (8 * \x, 8 * \y) node[inner sep=0, outer sep = -0.1pt,color=black,fill,circle] (node-\k) {};
};

\foreach \x / \y / \z / \trash in
{
4/5/8/0,
9/11/16/0,
9/16/17/0,
11/10/18/0,
11/18/16/0,
10/8/15/0,
10/15/18/0,
8/5/12/0,
8/12/15/0,
5/2/6/0,
5/6/12/0,
2/1/3/0,
2/3/6/0,
17/16/24/0,
16/18/23/0,
16/23/24/0,
18/15/22/0,
18/22/23/0,
15/12/19/0,
15/19/22/0,
12/6/13/0,
12/13/19/0,
6/3/7/0}
{
\draw[fill=red]  (node-\x) --  (node-\y) --  (node-\z) -- cycle;
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document})
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please indent code block with 4 spaces (not 8) or use CTRL+K to do this automatically. Please no signatures or gratitude lines at the end.

Comment: I executed your code, it seems you want to draw some strips of red triangles. Wouldn't there be much less complicated ways than this, e.g. nesting two `\foreach` loops? I mean I'm really puzzled _why_ you want to draw some triangles this way?

Comment: First of all, those are not nested loops. Then, do you have something in mind more efficient to draw a bunch of triangles not knowing _apriori_ the position of each vertices **and** the number of triangles ?

Comment: @BenDover You have lists of coordinates, so I assume you know things _apriori_, or are these list dynamically generated? Regarding the `foreach`: I just saw that your code produced more or less three stripes of similar triangles, and that would be a task for such a loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because you're drawing your lines between the *edges* of your circle nodes, which means that the resulting shapes are not closed and thus cannot be filled. You can fill your triangles by using the node `center`s instead of just the node names:

```
\draw [fill=red]  (node-\x.center) --  (node-\y.center) --  (node-\z.center) -- cycle;
```

This will, however, lead to the filled triangles partially overpainting the circles. To avoid this, you can load the `backgrounds` library and enclose your loop in `\begin{pgfonlayer}{background} ... \end{pgfonlayer}`:

```
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\foreach \x / \y / \z / \trash in
{
4/5/8/0,
9/11/16/0,
9/16/17/0,
11/10/18/0,
11/18/16/0,
10/8/15/0,
10/15/18/0,
8/5/12/0,
8/12/15/0,
5/2/6/0,
5/6/12/0,
2/1/3/0,
2/3/6/0,
17/16/24/0,
16/18/23/0,
16/23/24/0,
18/15/22/0,
18/22/23/0,
15/12/19/0,
15/19/22/0,
12/6/13/0,
12/13/19/0,
6/3/7/0}
{
    \draw [fill=red]  (node-\x.center) --  (node-\y.center) --  (node-\z.center) -- cycle;
}
\end{pgfonlayer}
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the `center` of the node explicitly, otherwise the boundary of the node is taken and this seems to cause an non-closed paths.

Use:

```
\draw[fill=red]  (node-\x.center) --  (node-\y.center) --  (node-\z.center) -- cycle;
```

instead of:

```
\draw[fill=red]  (node-\x) --  (node-\y) --  (node-\z) -- cycle;
```

This can be avoided when you use `\coordinate`s instead of `\node`s. However, here you also want to draw the nodes as little dots, which can't be done with coordinates.